# Cannot Delete CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I had a Django Project that I created using CodeStar.   I then tried adjusting the template.yml file and adjusting the parameters.   Unfortunately, this has created a mess and the changes did not deploy correctly, so I wanted to clear everything out and start again and unfortunately I think I may have deleted things in the wrong order.   I have deleted the Elastic Beanstalk environments, but I still have two CloudFormation environments that I cannot delete.   They keep coming up with the following error message:

In red at the top:

```
arn:aws:iam::224836348178:role/CodeStarWorker-myebdjangoproje-CloudFormation is invalid or cannot be assumed
```

When I click into the stacks:

```
DELETE_FAILED

The following resource(s) failed to delete: [EBApplication, EBEnvironment].
```

I would appreciate any help with how to clean this up?

Thanks

Comment: the cloudformation will display the reason as well why it was unable to delete the `[EBApplication, EBEnvironment]`

Comment: Just before the deletion failed, it says:

Comment: Just before the deletion fails in cloudformation, it says:   Role arn:aws:iam::224836348178:role/CodeStarWorker-myebdjangoproje-CloudFormation is invalid or cannot be assumed

Comment: https://dev.to/david_j_eddy/how-to-fix-failed-to-delete-stack-role--is-invalid-or-cannot-be-assumed-in-aws-cloudformation-3aip

Comment: That's great and now I think about it, a bit obvious.   I'm quite new to AWS, so thanks for the help.